# VBA do not copy range to .ppt

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I want VBA to paste all the Worksheets into example PPT, which started from particular slide, for example slide NUM.3

However the code which is in use right now, do not paste the selected area into PPT file. Could you help me?

Here is my code:

```
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z100")
'        Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(myPresentation.Slides.Count + 1, 12)
'        SlideNumb = myPresentation.Slides.Count
        Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(SlideNumb).Select '(myPresentation.Slides.Count + 1, 12) '(myPresentation.Slides.Count + 1, 12)
        rng.Copy
        mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
        Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
            myShape.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            myShape.Left = 36.72
            myShape.Top = 112.32
            myShape.Width = 854.64
            myShape.Height = 397.44
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ShtNum = ShtNum + 1
        SlideNumb = SlideNumb + 1
    Next ws
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(SlideNumb).Select
```

To this:

```
Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(SlideNumb)
```

Delete this:

```
    Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
        myShape.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        myShape.Left = 36.72
        myShape.Top = 112.32
        myShape.Width = 854.64
        myShape.Height = 397.44
```

remove the comments and give it a try again.

Comment: Thanks, first line was the right thing and now is working :)

Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(SlideNumb)

But the second part, which is for shape adjustments I really need that.